# Is it possible to overwrite the behavior of materialize css navbar and make it into a bootstrap style?

Tags: materialize

I was thinking to use bootstrap and materialize css but it happen that they have the same class.

Comment: You can customize the navbar in your css and add @important flags.

Comment: yeah. thats what exactly what im thinking. after using important flags is that ill need to modify the jquery codes which will give me a another problem. i was thinking to just use a pure owned css and jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom style to an object that already has it's style defined by other css class, sometimes you will have to replace some styles. Here's how to do it:

Firstly, check which class overrides it.
Let's say your markup returns: 
`<div class="range-specific range"></div>`

If your css is defined like that:
`.range-specific { foo; }`

`.range { bar; }`

Then the range will win.

If you change it to:
.range-specific.range { foo; } 
.range { bar; } `

Then the specific will win.

If you want to hack it even more, do this:
`.range-specific.range-specific { foo; }`
`.range { bar; }`

And specific will surely win.

It's even better to do this:
`.range { bar; }`
`.range-specific { foo; }`

*If u want to override that class you can use `nav.app-bg` or use !important*
[Here you can check Overrides of Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/)

Comment: this is actually beyond my expectation man and it was too advanced or could be intermediate for me .i was thinking to just use a pure owned css and jquery. THANKS A LOT FOR THIS..